# $\Bbb Z/2$ is the only Boolean ring that is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove that the only Boolean ring that is an integral domain is $Z/2Z$.

I know that the definition of a Boolean ring is $a^2=a$ and that an integral domain is $ab=0$ either $a=0$ or $b=0$. But yet i still can not solve the problem any idea  please.

Comment: If $a^2 = a$ and $a$ is different from 0 and 1, try $a(1-a)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

In a Boolean ring:

$a(a-1)=0$

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a Boolean ring and an integral domain. For each $r \in R$, $r(r - 1) = r^2 - r = 0$. Hence, for each $r \in R$, $r = 0$ or $r - 1 = 0$, i.e., $r$ is either $0$ or $1$. So $R$ is the ring with two elements, i.e., $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in R$. $a^2 = a$, implies that $a^2 - a =0$, $a(a-1)=0$. either $a = 0$ or $a-1=0$, thus $a=1$. Therefore $R$ is $Z/2Z$.

Comment: Why does $a(a-1) = 0$ imply that either $a = 0$ or $a - 1 = 0$? It seems like you are assuming you have an integral domain, which is in fact what you want to prove.